# Ionic 3 camera plugin not working in Asus and some samsung mobile in android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, asus

I am facing an issue of `Ionic 3` camera plugin , which is not working in Some `ASUS` and `SAMSUNG` Android mobile. I am using this ionic plugin: -

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 50,
        sourceType: sourceType,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        targetWidth: 450,
        targetHeight: 450,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true
      };
```

please guide me if any solution for these problem.

Comment: Please provide the error that you are getting.

Comment: The response of that plugin is not getting properly, It goes inside plugin error block, Didn't get any response of that plugin.